# How to measure in $\sigma_x$ basis in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms

As we know, Qiskit can give us the results of our measurements in computational or, better to say, $\sigma_z$ basis. However, I am courageous about measuring the qubit in, for instance, $\sigma_x$ basis. In $\sigma_x$ basis, we have to projective measurements such that $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$. Here, how can we realize that we have measured the state of the qubit in either $|+\rangle$ or $|-\rangle$?

Comment: Literally, I have read this answer. However, my goal is to do some continuous mid-measurements on the qubit in $\sigma{x}$ basis. I want to have a clear outcome whether the result was + or -.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what a "continuous mid-measurement" is or maybe state what the equivalent method is in the $\sigma_z$ basis is? I think this might help us understand what you are looking for that's different to just "put an $H$ gate before you measure"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit long for a comment but my goal is to explain that the answer linked as duplicate does indeed answer your question.

The `measure` operation of qiskit measures in the computational basis, there's no way around that (though [it may change in the future](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/pull/9269)).

However, it is possible to simulate a measurement in the $X$-basis using a measurement in the computational basis. To keep things simple, I'll stick to single qubit pure states here, but the reasoning is identical for more qubits and mixed states.

When measuring a state $|\psi\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|0\rangle$ in the computational basis, we measure $|0\rangle$ with probability $|\alpha|^2$, and $|1\rangle$ with probability $|\beta|^2$.

When measuring the aforementioned state in the computational basis, we measure $|+\rangle$ with probability $$|\langle+|\psi\rangle|^2=\frac{|\alpha+\beta|^2}{2}$$ and $|1\rangle$ with probability $$|\langle-|\psi\rangle|^2=\frac{|\alpha-\beta|^2}{2}$$

Now, suppose we apply an Hadamard gate on $|\psi\rangle$, we end up with:
$$H|\psi\rangle=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle$$

Thus, if we now measure the state in the computational basis, we will measure $|0\rangle$ with probability $|\langle+|\psi\rangle|^2$ and $|1\rangle$ with probability $|\langle-|\psi\rangle|^2$. Thus, if we finally apply an Hadamard gate after having measured, we would have perfectly simulated a measurement in the $X$-basis using a measurement in the computational basis.

---

More generally, for an arbitrary number of qubits, when you want to measure in a given basis, it will always be possible to write this basis as $(U|i\rangle)_i$. If you apply $U^\dagger$ to $|\psi\rangle$ and measure in the computational basis, you will measure $|i\rangle$ with probability:
$$\left|\langle i|U^\dagger|\psi\rangle\right|^2$$
Which is exactly the probability to measure $U|i\rangle$ if we measure in the $(U|i\rangle)_i$ basis. You then simply need to apply $U$ to simulate a measurement in this basis using one in the computational basis.